# Why doesn't $\binom{13}{3}\binom{4}{2}\binom{4}{2}4$ count the number of two pairs in a five card hand?

Tags: combinatorics

I understand the logic of the number of two pair hands in a five card hand being

$$\binom{13}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{4}{2}44$$

However, I also sympathize with the logic: choose three face values, then two suits for the first, two suits for the second, and a suit for the card not in a pair. Hence

$$\binom{13}{3}\binom{4}{2}\binom{4}{2}4$$

Why is this logic or counting of that logic incorrect?

Comment: "first"? "second"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The probability of being dealt a 2 pair 5 card hand...](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/586178/the-probability-of-being-dealt-a-2-pair-5-card-hand)

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown, right, I wondered if ordering had something to do with it... but isn't the logic of the correct counting liable to the same? Choose the suit of the first pair, then the second?

Comment: @JohnColtraneisJC In my optics this is not a duplicate. The OP asks what is wrong with some logic that is not treated in the other question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error you made is that you have to choose which of the three suits is the singleton.  Notice that 
$$\binom{3}{1}\binom{13}{3}\binom{4}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{4}{1} = \binom{13}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{44}{1}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let us make things more simple and work with a deck that has $12$ cards ($3$ ranks of $4$ suites). Then the first method gives:$$\binom32\binom42\binom424$$ possibilities, and the second gives:$$\binom33\binom42\binom424=\binom42\binom424$$ possibilities.

According to second method from $2$ "unselected" ranks a pair is selected.

Repairing this (by selecting the ranks) we get the first (correct) method.